# Negotiate maximum request body size with remote server before sending a POST

Tags: node.js, rest, http, httprequest

I have a Node JS server that is sending JSON objects of indeterminate size to a remote server whose limit on the body request size may not be known ahead of time.

In the event that my JSON object exceeds the maximum request size, I want to send the data in chunks.

I'm testing a mock implementation of the remote server that uses the npm library body-parser to set up its maximum request body size. When I sent a request that exceeded this limit, the mock remote server returned the error: `PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large`

Question: Is there a way to determine the maximum request body size accepted by a server via the standard HTTP methods and headers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you'll be able to query a remote server to directly get it's max.

Probably your best bet is to try a 'check and see' approach where you start with a reasonable value and switch to chunking by reducing it by some ratio every time you get rejected with a 413.

I would guess that an 8mb-10mb is a good starting size for general internet servers. But in your particular application you might know some extra constraints about the type of servers it would connect to and the typical size of data you're trying to send, so you might be able to use a bigger default value.

I'm not sure I'd recommend it but here's a dumb script that sends a bunch of dummy requests to binary search that google.com's max size is 4096 bytes.

```
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

function compute_size(domain) {
  var max_size = 10240;
  var min_size = 0;

  function send_req(size) {
    var post_data = '*'.repeat(size)
    var post_options = {
      host: domain,
      port: '80',
      path: '/',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Length': size
      }
    };

    var req = http.request(post_options, function(res) {
      console.log('Try for size ' + size + ': ' + res.statusCode);
      var fn;

      if (res.statusCode == 413) {
        max_size = size;
        fn = Math.floor;
      } else {
        min_size = size;
        fn = Math.ceil;
      }

      var next_size = fn((max_size - min_size)/2+min_size);

      if (next_size == max_size || next_size == min_size) {
        console.log('Found max: ', min_size);
      } else {
        send_req(next_size);
      }
    });

    req.write(post_data);
    req.end();

  }

  send_req(max_size);
}

compute_size('google.com');
```

Here's the output for google.com, deducing the max of 4096... lol

```
$ node post.js
Try for size 10240: 413
Try for size 5120: 413
Try for size 2560: 405
Try for size 3840: 405
Try for size 4480: 413
Try for size 4160: 413
Try for size 4000: 405
Try for size 4080: 405
Try for size 4120: 413
Try for size 4100: 413
Try for size 4090: 405
Try for size 4095: 405
Try for size 4098: 413
Try for size 4096: 405
Try for size 4097: 413
Found max:  4096
```

Comment: It sounds like we're going to have to verbally determine the limit ahead of time with the business client hosting this remote server. For development purposes, I'm going to use the max that you got from google.com. Thanks a bunch, this is a neat way to find the max size.